# Generating a .docx document from a .dotx template with docx4j (in an XPages application)

Tags: java, ms-word, xpages, docx4j

I'm using docx4j in an XPages application to create Word documents containing content from an XPage. The Word document (in .docx format) is created based on a template (also in docx.format). This all works fine. However, when I change the template from a .docx to a .dotx format, the Word document (.docx) which is generated cannot be opened. On trying to open the document, I get an error saying that the content causes problems.

Can anyone tell me how to convert a .dotx file to a .docx file using docx4j?

The code I am currently using is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

import org.docx4j.XmlUtils;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.wml.ContentAccessor;

import org.slf4j.impl.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.docx4j.wml.*;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.*;

import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.DocumentSettingsPart;
import org.docx4j.jaxb.Context;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.relationships.RelationshipsPart;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.relationships.Namespaces;

public class JavaTemplateDocument {


    public void mainCode(Session session, Document currDoc, String empLang, String templateType, String sArt) throws Exception {

        Database dbCurr = session.getCurrentDatabase(); 
        String viewName = "vieTemplateLookup"; 
        View tview = dbCurr.getView(viewName);
        Vector viewKey = new Vector();
        viewKey.addElement(empLang);
        viewKey.addElement(templateType);
        Document templateDoc = tview.getDocumentByKey(viewKey);
        if (tview.getDocumentByKey(viewKey) == null ) System.out.println("templateDoc is NULL");

        Item itmNotesFields = templateDoc.getFirstItem("NotesFieldList");
        Item itmWordFields = templateDoc.getFirstItem("WordFieldList");

        Vector<String[]> notesFields = itmNotesFields.getValues();
        Vector<String[]> wordFields = itmWordFields.getValues();

        int z = notesFields.size();
        int x = wordFields.size();

        Enumeration e1 = notesFields.elements();

        Enumeration e2 = wordFields.elements();

        WordprocessingMLPackage template = getTemplate("C:\\Temp\\AZG Sample Template.dotx","C:\\Temp\\AZG Sample Template.docx");

        for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) { 
        if (currDoc.hasItem(String.valueOf(notesFields.elementAt(y)))) {
        Item itmNotesName = currDoc.getFirstItem(String.valueOf(notesFields.elementAt(y))); 
        replacePlaceholder(template, itmNotesName.getText(), String.valueOf(wordFields.elementAt(y))); } 
        else {
            replacePlaceholder(template, "", String.valueOf(wordFields.elementAt(y)));
        }
        }

        writeDocxToStream(template, "C:\\Temp\\AZG Sample Document.docx");
        createResponseDocument(dbCurr, currDoc, templateDoc, sArt); 
    }

    private void createResponseDocument(Database dbCurr, Document currDoc, Document templateDoc, String sArt) throws NotesException{

        Document respDoc = dbCurr.createDocument(); // create the response document
        String refVal = currDoc.getUniversalID();

        respDoc.appendItemValue("IsDocTemplate", "1"); 
        if (currDoc.hasItem("Name")) {
            respDoc.appendItemValue("Name", currDoc.getItemValue("Name"));}
        else {System.out.println("Name is not available"); }
        if (currDoc.hasItem("Firstname")) {
            respDoc.appendItemValue("Firstname", currDoc.getItemValue("Firstname"));}
        else {System.out.println("Firstname is not available"); }
        if (currDoc.hasItem("ReferenceTypeTexts")) {
            respDoc.appendItemValue("ReferenceTypeTexts", currDoc.getItemValue("ReferenceTypeTexts"));}
        else {System.out.println("ReferenceTypeTexts is not available"); }
        if (currDoc.hasItem("ReferenceType")) {
            respDoc.appendItemValue("ReferenceType", currDoc.getItemValue("ReferenceType"));}
        else {System.out.println("ReferenceType is not available"); }   
        System.out.println("Append Form value");
        respDoc.appendItemValue("Form", "frmRespTempl"); 


        respDoc.makeResponse(currDoc);
        RichTextItem body = respDoc.createRichTextItem("Body");
        body.embedObject(1454, "", "C:\\Temp\\AZG Sample Document.docx", null);
        respDoc.save();
    }


    /*
     * Create a simple word document that we can use as a template. 
     * For this just open Word, create a new document and save it as template.docx. 
     * This is the word template we'll use to add content to. 
     * The first thing we need to do is load this document with docx4j. 
     */

    private WordprocessingMLPackage getTemplate(String source, String target) throws Docx4JException, FileNotFoundException, IOException { 

    String WORDPROCESSINGML_DOCUMENT = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-   officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml";
    final ContentType contentType = new ContentType(WORDPROCESSINGML_DOCUMENT);

    String templatePath = source;

    File sourceFile = new File(source);
    File targetFile = new File(target);
    copyFileUsingFileChannels(sourceFile, targetFile);

    WordprocessingMLPackage template = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new FileInputStream(targetFile));

    ContentTypeManager ctm = wordMLPackage.getContentTypeManager();
        ctm.addOverrideContentType(new URI("/word/document.xml"),WORDPROCESSINGML_DOCUMENT);

    DocumentSettingsPart dsp = new DocumentSettingsPart();
        CTSettings settings = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTSettings();
        dsp.setJaxbElement(settings);
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(dsp); 

        // Create external rel
        RelationshipsPart rp = RelationshipsPart.createRelationshipsPartForPart(dsp);
        org.docx4j.relationships.Relationship rel = new org.docx4j.relationships.ObjectFactory().createRelationship();
        rel.setType( Namespaces.ATTACHED_TEMPLATE );
        rel.setTarget(templatePath);
        rel.setTargetMode("External");
        rp.addRelationship(rel); // addRelationship sets the rel's @Id 

        settings.setAttachedTemplate(
        (CTRel)XmlUtils.unmarshalString("<w:attachedTemplate xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\" r:id=\"" + rel.getId() + "\"/>", Context.jc, CTRel.class)
        );

    return template;
}

    private static List<Object> getAllElementFromObject(Object obj, Class<?> toSearch) {
        List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
        if (obj instanceof JAXBElement) obj = ((JAXBElement<?>) obj).getValue();

        if (obj.getClass().equals(toSearch))
            result.add(obj);
        else if (obj instanceof ContentAccessor) {
            List<?> children = ((ContentAccessor) obj).getContent();
            for (Object child : children) {
                result.addAll(getAllElementFromObject(child, toSearch));
            }

        }
        return result;
    }

    /*
     * This will look for all the Text elements in the document, and those that match are replaced with the value we specify.
     */

    private void replacePlaceholder(WordprocessingMLPackage template, String name, String placeholder ) {
        List<Object> texts = getAllElementFromObject(template.getMainDocumentPart(), Text.class);

        for (Object text : texts) {
            Text textElement = (Text) text;
            if (textElement.getValue().equals(placeholder)) {
                textElement.setValue(name);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * write the document back to a file
     */

    private void writeDocxToStream(WordprocessingMLPackage template, String target) throws IOException, Docx4JException {
        File f = new File(target);
        template.save(f);
    }

    /*
     * Example code for replaceParagraph
     * 
        String placeholder = "SJ_EX1";
        String toAdd = "jos\ndirksen";

        replaceParagraph(placeholder, toAdd, template, template.getMainDocumentPart());
     */

    private void replaceParagraph(String placeholder, String textToAdd, WordprocessingMLPackage template, ContentAccessor addTo) {
        // 1. get the paragraph
        List<Object> paragraphs = getAllElementFromObject(template.getMainDocumentPart(), P.class);

        P toReplace = null;
        for (Object p : paragraphs) {
            List<Object> texts = getAllElementFromObject(p, Text.class);
            for (Object t : texts) {
                Text content = (Text) t;
                if (content.getValue().equals(placeholder)) {
                    toReplace = (P) p;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // we now have the paragraph that contains our placeholder: toReplace
        // 2. split into seperate lines
        String as[] = StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens(textToAdd, '\n');

        for (int i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
            String ptext = as[i];

            // 3. copy the found paragraph to keep styling correct
            P copy = (P) XmlUtils.deepCopy(toReplace);

            // replace the text elements from the copy
            List<?> texts = getAllElementFromObject(copy, Text.class);
            if (texts.size() > 0) {
                Text textToReplace = (Text) texts.get(0);
                textToReplace.setValue(ptext);
            }

            // add the paragraph to the document
            addTo.getContent().add(copy);
        }

        // 4. remove the original one
        ((ContentAccessor)toReplace.getParent()).getContent().remove(toReplace);

    }

    /*
     * A set of hashmaps that contain the name of the placeholder to replace and the value to replace it with. 
     * 
     *  Map<String,String> repl1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        repl1.put("SJ_FUNCTION", "function1");
        repl1.put("SJ_DESC", "desc1");
        repl1.put("SJ_PERIOD", "period1");

        Map<String,String> repl2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        repl2.put("SJ_FUNCTION", "function2");
        repl2.put("SJ_DESC", "desc2");
        repl2.put("SJ_PERIOD", "period2");

        Map<String,String> repl3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        repl3.put("SJ_FUNCTION", "function3");
        repl3.put("SJ_DESC", "desc3");
        repl3.put("SJ_PERIOD", "period3");

        replaceTable(new String[]{"SJ_FUNCTION","SJ_DESC","SJ_PERIOD"}, Arrays.asList(repl1,repl2,repl3), template);
     */

    private void replaceTable(String[] placeholders, List<Map<String, String>> textToAdd,
            WordprocessingMLPackage template) throws Docx4JException, JAXBException {
        List<Object> tables = getAllElementFromObject(template.getMainDocumentPart(), Tbl.class);

        // 1. find the table
        Tbl tempTable = getTemplateTable(tables, placeholders[0]);
        List<Object> rows = getAllElementFromObject(tempTable, Tr.class);

        // first row is header, second row is content
        if (rows.size() == 2) {
            // this is our template row
            Tr templateRow = (Tr) rows.get(1);

            for (Map<String, String> replacements : textToAdd) {
                // 2 and 3 are done in this method
                addRowToTable(tempTable, templateRow, replacements);
            }

            // 4. remove the template row
            tempTable.getContent().remove(templateRow);
        }
    }

    private Tbl getTemplateTable(List<Object> tables, String templateKey) throws Docx4JException, JAXBException {
        for (Iterator<Object> iterator = tables.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Object tbl = iterator.next();
            List<?> textElements = getAllElementFromObject(tbl, Text.class);
            for (Object text : textElements) {
                Text textElement = (Text) text;
                if (textElement.getValue() != null && textElement.getValue().equals(templateKey))
                    return (Tbl) tbl;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void addRowToTable(Tbl reviewtable, Tr templateRow, Map<String, String> replacements) {
        Tr workingRow = (Tr) XmlUtils.deepCopy(templateRow);
        List<?> textElements = getAllElementFromObject(workingRow, Text.class);
        for (Object object : textElements) {
            Text text = (Text) object;
            String replacementValue = (String) replacements.get(text.getValue());
            if (replacementValue != null)
                text.setValue(replacementValue);
        }

        reviewtable.getContent().add(workingRow);
    }

private static void copyFileUsingFileChannels(File source, File dest)
                throws IOException {
            FileChannel inputChannel = null;
            FileChannel outputChannel = null;
            try {
                inputChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
                outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
                outputChannel.transferFrom(inputChannel, 0, inputChannel.size());
            } finally {
                inputChannel.close();
                outputChannel.close();
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Interesting. I'd be tempted to try and suss out the structural differences between .dotx and .docx files, perhaps by comparing a file that has been converted successfully, using a tool like [DOTX to DOCX Converter](http://techblissonline.com/dotx-what-is-dotx-file/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly, there are a few things that comprise the difference between a template (.dotx) and a document (.docx). This means you have a few things that you need to do -- it's not as simple as just changing the file extension, whether you're saving a doc **as** a template, or attempting to create a document **from** a template.

Hopefully this outline will assist:

1. First do what you've already done: your new document should be a file copy of the template
2. Change your new `WordprocessingMLPackage`'s document type as appropriate (see `WORDPROCESSINGML_TEMPLATE` in the `ContentTypes` class)
3. Create an attached template and attach it to your document: see the [sample code on Github](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/TemplateAttach.java) for more detail on that (`TemplateAttach.java` sample).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing some testing and a problem occurs already after the template is copied. After copying the .dotx to a .docx, the resulting .docx can not be opened on the file system.

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm trying to follow your suggestions but so far no luck. I just can't seem to change the content type. I've updated my code to (particularly the "getTemplate" method).

Comment: I've finally gotten this working by adding - ContentTypeManager ctm = wordMLPackage.getContentTypeManager();
  ctm.addOverrideContentType(new URI("/word/document.xml"),WORDPROCESSINGML_DOCUMENT); - I've updated the getTemplate method in the code. Ben, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Let's hack it.
New office formats are just ZIPs with many XML configurations and data. Try to save identical document as template and document in MS Word. IMHO the core of your problem is in (packed) file `[Content_Types].xml`.

They differ in the property:

ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.**template**.main+xml"
ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.**document**.main+xml"

I would expect @benpoole's advice should work (it should alter the content of said file). If that is not the case, simply hack the content of it inside the file (it is just ordinary ZIP archive, remember).

**Disclaimer**: there IS difference in few more files, that might need tweaking to make it work.

Comment: String WORDPROCESSINGML_DOCUMENT = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml";
  final ContentType contentType = new ContentType(WORDPROCESSINGML_DOCUMENT);
File sourceFile = new File(source); // .dotx
File targetFile = new File(target); // .docx
copyFileUsingFileChannels(sourceFile, targetFile);
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new FileInputStream(targetFile));
wordMLPackage.setContentType(contentType);  - is how I'm trying to update the ContentType (as in updated code above) but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you need to change the returning filename to a dotx from docx
do a filecopy from docx to dotx and change this row

```
 body.embedObject(1454, "", "C:\\Temp\\AZG Sample Document.dotx", null);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Fredrik. Actually I want to convert a .dotx template to a .docx file using docx4j. I've now updated my question. I tried doing a filecopy as you suggested but I'm afraid that I still have the same problem. To copy the file, I added a method "copyFileUsingFileChannels" which I have added to the bottom of my code. I've also updated the getTemplate method.